# Sorting Mongo records on non unique created date time field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am sorting on `created` field which is in the form of 2022-03-26T03:56:13.176+00:00 and is a representation of a `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Sorting by only `created` is not consistent as the field is not unique, due to batch operations that run quickly enough to result in duplicates.

I've added a second sort, on `_id`, which is ObjectId.

It seems the second sort adds quite a bit of time to the query, more so than the first, which is odd to me.

Why does it more than double response time, and is there a more preferred way to ensure the order?

Using MongoTemplate, I sort like this:

```
query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Order.desc("createdOn"), Sort.Order.desc("_id")));
```

Comment: You can create compound indexes (index on multiple fields) and also sort on multiple fields. Also, you can check if your query using the required index for the query by generating a query plan (using the `explain()`). The query plan will not show a `SORT STAGE`, in case of usage of the index for the sort operation.

Answer (score 1):

If your use case is always to sort in descending order on both fileds it is best to create the compound index in the expected sort order as follow:

```
 db.collection.createIndex({ createdOn:-1,_id:-1 })
```

But in general the default _id field is containing the document insertion date and it is unique accross mongodb process so you may just sort based on _id , you most porbably don't need to sort additionally on createdOn date ...